# What is the difference between "," and "or" in always @?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is there a difference between using `,` and `or` in `always @`.

For example:

```
always @(S or C)
```

and

```
always @(S,C)
```

If there is a difference, what is it?

Answer (score 3):

They're synonymous. There's no difference whatsoever.

Also, consider using `always @(*)` for combinational blocks; it's supported by all modern synthesis tools, and automatically makes the block sensitive to any signals referenced in the block.

If you're using SystemVerilog, you should consider using `always_comb` instead.

Comment: There was a time that a big simulation and synthesis company had a bug in always_comb ongoing for many years (With various "fixes"). We never trusted it to be really fixed and I have thus avoided using it.

Comment: @oldfart couldn't be that many years as SystemVerilog synthesis support is relatively new(10 years) compared with Verilog(30 years)

Comment: Also, if I were to choose, I would go for the `or` syntax  - it explicitly states the intention.

Comment: Just want to say that you do (and should) use this feature all the time outside of testbenches for asynchronous resets on registers `always @(posedge clk, negedge resetB)`; its the exact same construct. Agree completely for combinational logic, implicit sensitivity lists are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference; they are alternative syntaxes for the same behavior. Originally (in the 1980s) Verilog only allowed `@(S or C)`, but many people confused that with `@(S || C)`. That means wait for a change in the *result* of the logical or expression `S || C`. Further complicating matters is that VHDL uses `or` for their logical boolean operator. So `@(S, C)` was added probably before 1990 to avoid confusion with the logical operator.

Note that for synthesizable combinational logic, you should be using implicit sensitivity with either

```
alway @(*)  // ... Verilog
always_comb // ... SystemVerilog
```